# Detecting Rightclick in TigerJython

Tags: jython, turtle-graphics, right-click

I want to detect a right-click in jython. Here I am using the gturtle module and I am trying to make the right-click fill shapes i drew.

```
from gturtle import*

def fillClick(x,y):
    fill(x,y)
makeTurtle(?=fillClick)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Listener.
Sample code:

```
from gturtle import*

def fillClick(x,y):
     fill(x,y)

wn = turtle.Screen()  # make the screen
wn.listen()  # Set up listener
wn.onclick(fillClick, 3) # 3 - right click, 1 - left click for windows. if 3 doesn't work, do 2(depends on your device). 
wn.mainloop()
```

Note, turtle plugs in the x, y by itself.

Edit: Note, you don't need "()" after fillClick function when using

```
wn.onclick(fillClick, 3).
```

Please comment if you have any questions.

Edit 2:
New sample code that represents what you want to do:

```
import turtle


def fillClick(x, y):
     t = turtle.Turtle()  # - make a turtle to "fill the place in"
     t.shape("circle")  # set shape to circle
     t.color("black")  # - set color to black
     t.penup()  # prevents a line following the turtle  
     turtle.tracer(0, 0)  # - disables screen refreshing
     t.goto(x, y)
     turtle.update()  # - update. 


wn = turtle.Screen()  # make the screen
wn.listen()  # Set up listener
wn.onclick(fillClick, 3)  # 3 - right click, 1 - left click for windows. if 3 doesn't work, do 2(depends on your device).
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, i'm on MacOS, I don't know if that's the reason though

Comment: Sorry, I botched that up, mixed up my left & right lol. try wn.onclick(fillClick, 3). IF that doesn't work, replace 2 with 3.

Comment: wait what python do you use? I use 3.8 I think

Comment: I don't know what Python I use, I use an IDE my School provides

Comment: Hmm, cuz I can't find a module named gturtle

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty weird, can I do something to help you?

Comment: I mean, If we dont use gturtle I think I can do something similar to what you want to do.

Comment: OK, thanks for helping out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I edited the original answer. Please go check it out!

Comment: Note, you probably already had a file name gturtle in your school's IDE. that's why you have a gturtle file that you can import and why others don't. IDK tho

Comment: Yeah, I searched gturtle up and no results. I think it's just a built-in thing from your school's IDE.

Comment: Doesn't even come past the import sequence, would it help if I send you over the .jar file because it isn't built into the IDE it's separate as .jar files

Comment: Wdym doesn't come past the import sequence? Do you think you don't have turtle installed?

Comment: Sure, send over the .jar file

Comment: As soon as I hit run it gives me an error in the first line of code

Comment: Hmmm. that means you don't even have a turtle module!

Comment: Ah, no I can't send the over the .jar files, i'm sorry, just forget about it, it's not that important. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No, its ok. I recommend using replit as a online IDE, or pycharm which works very well.

Comment: Here, look at this: https://repl.it/@jsun3/Right-Click#main.py

It has the code in it.  Click the green Run button.

Comment: May I ask what grade you are in and what IDE your school provided? Cuz my school doesn't even do computer science. AND YES, I DO GO TO SCHOOL, IM NOT THAT OLD!!!!

Comment: I'm in grade 10 and it's more that my country provided one. It's called TigerJython

Comment: Ok im searching it up rn.

Comment: Interesting, seems like in your IDE gturtle is defined.

Comment: Ok so I think gturtle is what your module uses for turtle. Ill try to make it work.

Comment: This is what I'm reading : https://www.tobiaskohn.ch/jython/turtle.html

Comment: It says "The turtle must be inside a closed shape. fill() will then cause it to fill the entire enclosed region with the current fill color. Alternatively, you can specify the point where the floodfill should start. A common mistake when using fill() is to have forgotten using penUp() before moving the turtle into the inside of a shape." for the fill function. So I think you need to do penup(), i.e turtle.penup() or OBJECT_HERE.penup(). It wont fix the problem, but I think its recommended.

Comment: I have no idea, but ill keep looking. It says mouseHit=fillClick should be fine on documentation, but its not working lmao

Comment: Which school uses TigerJython anyways? I recommend not worrying about this and watching *real* turtle tutorials and make *real* turtle programs that work on any good IDE. This guy's tutorials are pretty reliable most times: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7CiFhiTdvY.

Comment: If this is homework or worth A LOT of points, Ill still try to help tho.

Comment: Offical website for your IDE i think: https://www.tobiaskohn.ch/jython/turtlex.html

Comment: I believe this isnt python, I think its a mix of python, and some custom commands like the repeat function call. Also I think this was made by java. I cant answer this question, but if you want to learn python I really suggest learning basics with people like Tech with Tim. After your some what familiar with the basics, you can move on to game devoplment tutorials with python. SEARCH IT UP ON YOUTUBE!

Comment: Yeah I don't know, I'm new to coding, it's not that important and I could very well be that tigerJython isn't Python at all. You can just forget about it, I will try to learn real Python then.

Comment: Yeah, I've never heard about gturtle until now, and the repeat command? what the heck is it? In python, you use "while blank:" instead of "repeat num:".  Also, later on before you get into game dev with python, if you have discord and like discord bots, use should make your own discord bot like I did! Some tutorials are outdated however, so you gotta do some extra research.